# jq: replace string on specific entries

Tags: json

I am trying to replace the string - `some_string`  ( that could be any string ) with the `$val` value in the following file

```
more daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries": ["some_string:4000"]
    ,"registry-mirrors": ["http://some_string:4000"]
    ,"log-driver": "json-file"
    ,"log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "3"
    }
}
```

is it possible to do the replacing with `jq`?  on entries - `insecure-registries` and `registry-mirrors`

or if not `perl` one liner or `sed` will be also good

example of expected results , when `val=MG_SERVER.carpool.com`

```
more daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries": ["MG_SERVER.carpool.com:4000"]
    ,"registry-mirrors": ["http://MG_SERVER.carpool.com:4000"]
    ,"log-driver": "json-file"
    ,"log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "3"
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Judy - The answer to your question is: Yes.  In fact, jq would be an excellent choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply specify the changes in the jq statement separated with | and so:

```
jq '."insecure-registries"=["MG_SERVER.carpool.com:4000"] | ."registry-mirrors"=["http://MG_SERVER.carpool.com:4000"]' > daemon.json.tmp && mv -f daemon.json.tmp daemon.json
```

If the text to change to is contained in variables, the -arg flag of jq can be used and so assuming the texts to change to are stored in the variables val1 and val2 respectively:

```
jq --arg val1 "$val1" --arg val2 "$val2" '."insecure-registries"=[$val1] | ."registry-mirrors"=[$val2]' > daemon.json.tmp && mv -f daemon.json.tmp daemon.json
```

Output the changes to a temporary json file and then move the temporary file to daemon.json to write the changes.

Comment: what in case I want to use the $val instead that include the MG_SERVER.carpool.com

Comment: dose jq except the $val?

Comment: Yeah. I've amended the answer

Comment: `.key = [ $val ]` makes more sense than `.key[] = $val`. [See the difference](https://jqplay.org/s/njuyu3TNGX)

Comment: I think you mean jq --arg val1 "$val1" --arg val2 "$val2" '."insecure-registries"[]=$val1 | ."registry-mirrors"[]=$val2'  daemon.json.tmp && mv -f daemon.json.tmp daemon.json  , ( no need the ">" )

Comment: but as ikegami said better to do ./jq --arg val1 "$val1" --arg val2 "$val2" '."insecure-registries"=[ $val1 ] | ."registry-mirrors"=[ $val2 ]'  daemon.json.tmp

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer. Not including > doesn't make any sense, though as we need it to redirect the output to the tmp file before moving the tmp file to the original.

Comment: but can you please update the answer according to my previous notes?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great question. As there is very little activity on this post, I will preface this by saying that the solution posted helped me complete a task I needed from JQ as well.

### My Recommendations

---

For your current `daemon.json`:

```json
{
    "insecure-registries": ["some_string:4000"]
    ,"registry-mirrors": ["http://some_string:4000"]
    ,"log-driver": "json-file"
    ,"log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "3"
    }
}
```

It is possible to make the changes with the solutions provided; however, I was unable to work through the `>` *(file append operator)* through bash successfully.

### My Solution

---

```
cat daemon.json | jq --arg val "$val" '.configurations[2].program = $DEBUGSPROGRMSTR | .configurations[2].cwd = $DEBUGCWDSTR' "./launch.json" > newLaunch.json && cp -v newLaunch.json launch.json && rm -v newLaunch.json
```

I would recommend doing this command and trying your luck in bash.

### My Takeaway from the Posted Solutions

---

I had a very similar issue, but instead I am utilizing this feature of JQ, a great tool to configure my `launch.json` for my programming Katas Repo for my Codewars repo:

```sh
cat launch.json | jq --arg DEBUGSPROGRMSTR "$DEBUGSPROGRMSTR" --arg DEBUGCWDSTR "$DEBUGCWDSTR" '.configurations[2].program = $DEBUGSPROGRMSTR | .configurations[2].cwd = $DEBUGCWDSTR' "./launch.json" > newLaunch.json && cp -v newLaunch.json launch.json && rm -v newLaunch.json
```

This command takes the two variables approach from [@RamanSailopal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66031486/3025856), but actually works on my Mac. It copies the contents to a `newLaunch.json`, and then uses `cp -v` to show the contents returned after moving `newLaunch.json` to `launch.json`, after which the file is removed with the `rm -v newLaunch.json`.

This is the repo I've put together to work with this is at [CodeWars_Katas](https://github.com/GoodGuyGregory/codewars_katas). This is perfect for Hacktoberfest 2021, if you're interested in working with me.

Comment: This is a useful answer. Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), however, when linking to your own content; otherwise, answers like this might be interpreted as spam.